# Inject PHP with jquery, ajax

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to inject PHP into a div element on a wordpress blog page. I've got it to work with static content, but my script won't load PHP. My dynamic/PHP code:

```
<?php // data.php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'category' => 4, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
    // Get posts associated with category 4
     foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
              <?php 
                  global $more; 
                   $more=0;
                   the_content('read more');
               ?> 
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

And my ajax call:

```
(function($) {
  $("div#content-here").click(function(){
  var url = '/wp-content/themes/elevenchild/data.php';

  $("div#content-here").load(url);
});
})( jQuery );
```

Naturally my view has a

```
<div id="content-here"></div>
```

element.

My jquery library is loaded fine. I can inject simple HTML, so my method works, it just doesn't work with PHP? In the console it reports 500 Internal Server Error.

help

Comment: PHP only get's processed on the server side, not on the client side.

Comment: I believe you cannot inject php the way you want. On the moment the javascript will be loaded, the page is already rendered and on the client-side. The best you can do is to retrieve the pure HTML from your data.php and inject that.

Comment: can't call WP functions in your data.php without including WP core resources

Comment: 500 Internal Error means there is some misconfiguration on the server side, try to examine your error logs on the server. Another thing to try is to add things bit by bit: first try to retrieve some trivial HTML from that URI (.../data.php) then start putting some PHP code etc.

Answer (score 0):

It *won't work* like that. You've "injected" some PHP code in the page, and so what? That is because you've only done that on the already rendered page, that is, the one your client (the browser) already has received from the server. It doesn't even matter whether it's been a dynamically created or static HTML page, because what you see in your browser is "the end product" - static HTML.

Back to where we were - you've inserted some PHP code among the HTML. What you need now is the server to run that code. One way would be to send it back to the server, but that's not how that works. The server will only execute only PHP code ...within its jurisdiction, let's say (document root, etc). The way would be to inject your PHP code in the server files, but if that would be possible, then the whole website is compromised, which is does not happen that often fortunately.

Comment: Interesting comments. I can get the effect I'm looking for using the jquery.tools library, but my CSS let's me down slighly. That is across differing screen sizes. I can post a URL if anyone is willing to help?

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question :) You can then ask a new one, concerning your CSS issue.